# import uvicorn could not be resolved

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to create an api with fastapi.
I have installed and imported uvicorn and fastapi. However I get these errors messages:
 `Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError`
`No module named 'uvicorn'`  I have the same error for fastapi.

What shall I do ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add some code in the description?

Comment: You probably haven't installed those modules in that case - at least not in the environment where you're trying to run your code. What does `pip freeze` output when running in the same environment as where you're running your code? Do you have  `fastapi.py` or `uvicorn.py` files in the same directory as your project (the error should be different in that case, but still)

Comment: thanks, I found the pb. I uninstalled venv and reinstalled it with all the necessary libraries. and everything works :)